# Write something to the Internal app Cache dir

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm writing an app that needs to cache some files. The content it needs to cache is provided using a Reader reader or using a String. 
When I call the writeToCache function with the necessary arguments, it won't write a file to the cache dir. What am I doing wrong?? (using FX Browser I've checked the dir /SYSTEM (phone is rooted)/data/data/com.package/cache  it contains files but not the one with the specified file names)

Btw, the System.out.println(file.getPath()) outputs the right path!

This is the code to write the Reader object:

```
    /**
         *
         * @param reader The reader that contains the data that is used to parse the file
         * @param fileName the filename WITH extension
         */
            public void saveToCache(final Reader reader, String fileName){

                final File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), fileName);

                System.out.println("file.getPath() = " + file.getPath());

if(!file.exists()){
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

               if(reader == null){
                    System.err.println("reader == null!!");
                }

                Thread writeCache = new Thread(){

                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            OutputStream outStream;
                            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), 8 * 1024);

                            outStream.write(reader.read());
                            outStream.flush();
                            outStream.close();
                            Log.d("cacheManager", String.valueOf(reader.read()));

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                };

                System.out.println("savedItemToCache");
            }
```

This is the code to write the String object:

```
/**
     *
     * @param content The content that needs to be written
     * @param fileName the filename WITH extension
     */
    public void saveToCache(final String content, String fileName){

        final File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), fileName);

        System.out.println("file.getPath() = " + file.getPath());

if(!file.exists()){
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        if(content == null){
            System.err.println("content == null");
        }

        Thread writeCache = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    OutputStream outStream;
                    outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), 8 * 1024);

                    outStream.write(content.getBytes(), 0, content.getBytes().length);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("cacheManager", String.valueOf(content.getBytes()));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        System.out.println("savedItemToCache");

    }
```

Comment: FX File Explorer has no acces to your app's internal memory. Only if your device is rooted there is a chance. But with File.exists() you can easily check yopurself if the file exists.

Comment: @greenapps That's why I've put the (with root) in the path above ;-)

Comment: I saw that but it did not make me think that your device was rooted.

Comment: `Log.d("cacheManager", String.valueOf(reader.read()));`. Are you seeing this log statement?

Comment: Yes I am, I've updated the question

Comment: Why do you have two saveToCache functions? On the same file?

Comment: @greenapps One to save the contents of a reader and one to save the contents of a string

Comment: @greenapps No to a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
/**
     *
     * @param reader The InputStreamReader that contains the data that is used to parse the file
     * @param fileName the filename WITH extension
     */
        public void saveToCache(final Reader reader, String fileName){
            System.out.println("Saving item to cache");



            final File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), fileName);

            System.out.println("file.getPath() = " + file.getPath());

            if(!file.exists()){
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(reader == null){
                System.err.println("reader == null!!");
            }

            Thread writeCache = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Writing file!");
                        OutputStream outStream;
                        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                        String line = null;

                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                            outStream.write(line.getBytes());
                        }

                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            };

            writeCache.run();

            System.out.println("savedItemToCache");
        }
```

This method is used to get the contents of the cached file and put it into a reader object

```
/**
         *
         * @param fileName the filename WITH extension
         * @return The reader that you can use to parse the file
         * @throws ExecutionException
         * @throws InterruptedException
         */
            public Reader getFromCache(String fileName) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                System.out.println("getFromCache");

                final File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), fileName);

                try {
                      FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Reading from cache finished");

                return reader;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println("savedItemToCache");`. That is on the wrong place. You should put that at the end of the code in `run()`.

You only create Threads but forgot to `.start()` them.

Comment: All that is fixed, and a file is being written. But it only contains the first line of the actual response when using saveToCache(reader, fileName). The saveToCache(String , fileName) works fine

Comment: `But it only contains the first line of the actual response`. Response? Then show in code the lines which you write. And show how you read the file. Is the error in the writing or the reading is the question. Can you open the file with FX? What does it show?

Comment: If I open the code with fx, it only shows the first line :-P

Comment: Why arenot you telling more: the conclusion is that your save function is not ok. I already suggested what you should do now.

Comment: Yes that's right, both of the saveToCache methods are only writing one line. Do I need to iterate over the content.getBytes() in the saveToCache that saves a String? How do I iterate over the reader.read() method? I'm doing the best I can to provide you information :-P Thanks!

Comment: Show what you put in reader and how you call saveToCache so we can try that too.

Comment: The reader works, I use exactly the same reader to parse the json with gson. I'm sorry put I can't post the contents of that reader

Comment: Well thats sorry for you then.